# How to create a tuple of fix types whose size is a known at compile time in C++17?

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, stdtuple

I would like to create a tuple type of common element type whose length is known at compile time. For example if I have

```
static constexpr const std::size_t compiletime_size = 2;

using tuple_int_size_2 = magic (int, compiletime_size);
```

`tuple_int_size_2` should be the same type as `std::tuple<int, int>`

Comment: what about [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/tuple_size)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with recursion:

```
#include <tuple>

template <size_t N, typename Head, typename... T>
struct magic {
    using tuple_type = typename magic<N - 1, Head, Head, T...>::tuple_type;
};

template <typename... T>
struct magic<1, T...> {
    using tuple_type = std::tuple<T...>;
};

int main()
{
    auto t = typename magic<3, int>::tuple_type{};
    return 0;
}
```

I wonder, though, if `std::array` would be a much simpler and straight-forward solution to whatever task it is you're trying to solve.

Comment: I was hoping to extend it to the case of  magic (int, int_size, double, double_size, ...); so I can not use std::array

Answer (score 1):

Without recursion, with two declared (non defined) helper functions and a `using`

```
template <typename T, std::size_t ... Is>
constexpr auto gft_helper (std::index_sequence<Is...> const &)
   -> decltype(std::make_tuple( ((void)Is, std::declval<T>())... ));

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr auto get_fixed_tuple ()
  -> decltype(gft_helper<T>(std::make_index_sequence<N>{}));

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
using tuple_fixed_type = decltype(get_fixed_tuple<T, N>());
```

The following is a full working example

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

template <typename T, std::size_t ... Is>
constexpr auto gft_helper (std::index_sequence<Is...> const &)
   -> decltype(std::make_tuple( ((void)Is, std::declval<T>())... ));

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr auto get_fixed_tuple ()
  -> decltype(gft_helper<T>(std::make_index_sequence<N>{}));

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
using tuple_fixed_type = decltype(get_fixed_tuple<T, N>());

int main()
 {
   auto ft = tuple_fixed_type<long, 3u>{};

   static_assert( std::is_same<decltype(ft), std::tuple<long, long, long>>{} );
 }
```